# Pickadate seeding one filed from another

Tags: javascript, pickadate

I am trying to seed one field from another onChange, almost there but throwing an error when I try and access 'endDate' from within onSet, obviously I don't have access to it from within the function?:

```
var endDate = $('.end-date .datepicker').pickadate({
    formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
})

// Would like date from here copied over to endDate on change
var startDate = $('.start-date .datepicker').pickadate({
    formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    onSet: function(endDate) {
        console.log('Want to set endDate to - ' + this.get('select', 'yyyy/mm/dd'));
        endDate.set('select', this.get('select')); // This line is wrong ..
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This works..

```
// End date
var endDate = $('.end-date .datepicker').pickadate({
    formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
var picker_end_date = endDate.pickadate('picker');

// Start date, onset change enddate
var startDate = $('.start-date .datepicker').pickadate({
    formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    onSet: function(endDate) {
        //console.log('Want to set endDate to - ' + this.get('select', 'yyyy/mm/dd'));
        picker_end_date.set('select', this.get('select').obj);
    }
})
```